Keras RL DQNAgent error 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
I am tryng to train a multiheaded DQN agent with keras rl. I creted a custom environment with gym and when I try to build the agent i get the error "'list' object has no attribute 'shape'"
I tried using a simple network but then my actions become a scalar instead of the MultiBinary List that it should be
code for the environment
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box, MultiBinary, MultiDiscrete, Tuple, Dict
import numpy as np
import random as rn
import math
import pickle
#import taskGen as tg
#import Task as tk

#fatal error
#The observation space needs to be preprocessed and turned into a simple list

#note to self(don't keep accumulated reward here)
class TaskEnv(Env):
    #be careful
    #step = 0
    episodes = 100
    #task parameters
    locComp = 100 #local processors power in MIPS
    servComp = 2000 #server processor power in MIPS
    locEn =  10e-27#local processor energy requirement for each instruction
    servEn =  10#server processor energy requirement for each instruction
    transferSpeed = 600 #in Mbps
    transPower = 10e-3#10~25 milliwatt for wifi
    E2Tratio = 1#hyperparameter for energy to time importance ratio
    ETX = 1
    currentTasks = []
    
    
    #--------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        #load the task list
        with open ('StraightTaskList', 'rb') as fp:
            self.taskLister = pickle.load(fp)
        
        # Actions we can take
        #here it should come counting the dimentions
        self.ETX = 1#initial ETX
        self.placeInList = 0
        self.lenghtOfList = 100#number of time slots
        #this needs to change and come from the file, somehow
        self.dimen = 5#number of tasks in each time slot 
        self.action_space = MultiBinary(self.dimen) #each would be the offload or local decision for the task at hand
        self.observation_space = Box(-1, 20,shape=(((self.dimen) + 1), 1), dtype=np.float32) #as wide as the nodes
        #populating the first observation
        
        #print(self.observation_space[0])
        for i in range(0,self.dimen):
            
            #print('starting at: ', i)
            (locTimeCost,locEnergyCost) = self.localCost( (self.taskLister[(2*i)]) , (self.taskLister[((2*i)+1)]) )
            localReward = self.rewardFunction(locTimeCost,locEnergyCost)
            #print('local reward', localReward)
            
            (servTimeCost,servEnergyCost) = self.serverCost(self.taskLister[2*i],self.taskLister[(2*i) + 1])
            serverReward = self.rewardFunction(servTimeCost,servEnergyCost)
            #print('server reward', serverReward)
            accuReward = localReward - serverReward
            #print('total reward', accuReward)
            self.currentTasks.append(accuReward)
            
        self.currentTasks.append(self.ETX)
        #print(self.currentTasks)      
        # Set start state
        self.state = self.currentTasks #this is ETX at the end of flattened task list
        #print(self.state[0])
        self.counter = 0 #to count how many of the current time slot's task should be offloaded
        self.placeInList += self.dimen#go to step 1
        
        #self.currentTasks is the actual state and observation
        
        self.looperParam = 0
        
    #--------------------------------    
    def step(self, action):
        # Apply action, calculate reward
        reward = 0#not sure if i should reset the reward!!!
        self.counter = 0
        # Calculate reward based on action
        print('the actions in step: ',action)
        for a in range(0,self.dimen):
            if (action[a]):#if the action is to offload
                reward += self.currentTasks[a]
                self.counter += 1#add one to the count of offloaded tasks
            else:#if the action isn't to offload
                pass
        #updating the state for next step
        
        #code here for state update, old version wont work
        
        
        newETX = self.ETXcounter(self.counter)
        self.ETX = newETX
        self.counter = 0
        for i in range(0,self.dimen):
            
            #print('starting at: ', i)
            (locTimeCost,locEnergyCost) = self.localCost( (self.taskLister[self.placeInList +(2*i)]) , (self.taskLister[self.placeInList +((2*i)+1)]) )
            localReward = self.rewardFunction(locTimeCost,locEnergyCost)
            #print('local reward', localReward)
            
            (servTimeCost,servEnergyCost) = self.serverCost(self.taskLister[self.placeInList + (2*i)],self.taskLister[self.placeInList + (2*i) + 1])
            serverReward = self.rewardFunction(servTimeCost,servEnergyCost)
            #print('server reward', serverReward)
            accuReward = localReward - serverReward
            #print('total reward', accuReward)
            self.currentTasks[i]  = accuReward
            
        self.currentTasks[self.dimen] = newETX
        self.placeInList += self.dimen#go to the next timeslot
        
        observation = self.currentTasks
        print('observation is: ',observation)
        
        #observation = _get_obs(self,self.placeInList,self.state)
        
        # Check if the list is done
        if (self.placeInList<self.lenghtOfList):
            done = False
        else:
            done = True
        
        # Set placeholder for info
        info = {}
        
        # Return step information
        return observation, reward, done, info
#--------------------------------

#--------------------------------
    def render(self):
        # Implement viz
        pass
#--------------------------------    
    def reset(self):
        # Reset the states
        self.ETX = 1#initial ETX
        self.placeInList = 0
        
        for i in range(0,self.dimen):
            
            #print('starting at: ', i)
            (locTimeCost,locEnergyCost) = self.localCost( (self.taskLister[(2*i)]) , (self.taskLister[((2*i)+1)]) )
            localReward = self.rewardFunction(locTimeCost,locEnergyCost)
            #print('local reward', localReward)
            
            (servTimeCost,servEnergyCost) = self.serverCost(self.taskLister[2*i],self.taskLister[(2*i) + 1])
            serverReward = self.rewardFunction(servTimeCost,servEnergyCost)
            #print('server reward', serverReward)
            accuReward = localReward - serverReward
            #print('total reward', accuReward)
            self.currentTasks[i] = accuReward
            
        self.currentTasks[self.dimen] = (self.ETX)    
        # Set start state
        self.state = self.currentTasks
        self.counter = 0 #to count how many of the current time slot's task should be offloaded
        self.placeInList += self.dimen#go to step 1
        
        self.looperParam = 0
        return self.state

    
#--------------------------------    
    def ETXcounter(self,count):#a table of values from simulator
        if(count == 0):
            return 1
        elif(count == 1):
            return 1
        elif(count == 2):
            return math.floor(rn.uniform(2, 3.1))
        elif(count == 3):
            return math.floor(rn.uniform(3, 4.1))
        elif(count == 4):
            return math.floor(rn.uniform(4, 6.1))
        elif(count == 5):
            return 8
        elif(count == 6):
            return 10
        elif(count == 7):
            return 11
        elif(count == 8):
            return 12
        elif(count == 9):
            return 16
        elif(count == 10):
            return 18
        else:
            print('too many tasks')

#--------------------------------
    def get_action_meanings(self):
        return {0: "local computation", 1: "offload to server"}
#task functions
#--------------------------------    
    def localCost(self,taskWeight,ratio):
        wordSize = 32
        timeCost = (taskWeight*ratio)/(self.locComp)
        energyCost = (taskWeight*ratio)*(self.locEn)
        return(timeCost,energyCost)

    
#--------------------------------
    def serverCost(self,taskWeight,ratio):
        wordSize = 32
        timeCost = ((taskWeight*ratio)/(self.servComp)) + ((taskWeight/(self.transferSpeed*(10^6)))*self.ETX)
        energyCost = ((taskWeight/self.transferSpeed)*self.ETX*self.transPower)
        return(timeCost,energyCost)
#--------------------------------
    def rewardFunction(self,time,energy):
        return time + (self.E2Tratio*energy)#ratio tells us how important each part is (over 1, energy matters more)

code for the model
import gym 
import random

import FlatEnv as rt
#_____________________________________
import numpy as np
#from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input
#from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
#_____________________________________
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory



#_____________________________________Gym Class Wrapper for compatibility
class GymWrapper(gym.Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        gym.Wrapper.__init__(self, env)
        self.env = env

    def reset(self, **kwargs):
        obs = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
        npa = np.asarray(obs, dtype=np.float32)
        return npa

    def step(self, action):
        print(action)
        obs, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action)
        
        npa = np.asarray(obs, dtype=np.float32)
        return npa, reward, done, {}
    
    
#_____________________________________Create a Deep Learning Model with Keras
def build_model(states, actions):
    #model = Sequential()
    inputs = Input(shape=(1,6))#(inputs)
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
    y = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs= []
    for i in range(5):
        head = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(y)  # Linear for Q-values
        outputs.append(head)

    # Concatenate or add head outputs depending on the approach (Ensemble or Factored)
    print('\n\n\n\n')
    print('outpu is: ',outputs)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    print(policy)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
                  nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, gamma=0.99, target_model_update=1e-2)#maybe add gamma later
    return dqn
#_____________________________________testing the model

env = GymWrapper(rt.TaskEnv())
states = env.observation_space.shape
print('\n\n\n\n')
actions = env.action_space.n
#actions = np.array(env.action_space.shape)
print('actions are ',actions)

episodes = 100
samp = env.observation_space.sample()


model = build_model(states, [actions])
print('actions are ',actions)
model.summary()
dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
# #logger.setLevel(logger.ERROR)#study
#print(env)

dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=100, visualize=False, verbose=2)#verbose is for training log
print('here')
dqn.save_weights('dqn_weights.h5f', overwrite=True)
scores = dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=100, visualize=False)

# _ = dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=15, visualize=False)

I tried everyhting I knew, which here means nothing

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
